# How to highlight table column based on th text using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Say I have the following table:

```html
<table width=200 border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>Ignore</th>
    <th>Highlight</th>
    <th>Ignore</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>yep</td>
    <td>yep</td>
    <td>yep</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>yep</td>
      <td>yep</td>
      <td>yep</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and I want to highlight all **Highlight** columns. How do I do this based on the header text?

I realise it can be achieved by selecting the n'th child, but what to future proof it against likely column order changes.

```
$('body > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2)').css('background-color', 'pink');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8XSLF/

Comment: without specific classes, I guess it just cannot be "future proof"

Comment: the column name is guaranteed not to change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get index of `th` has **Highlight** text. So use [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector to selecting it and then use [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to finding index of it. At the end, select every `th` and `td` has index equal to finded index.

*Note that the `:contains()` selector select also element has unwanted text like `Highlighted` and `Text Highlighted`. If your table text isn't constant, use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead.*

```js
var i = $("table th:contains('Highlight')").index();
$("table tr th, table tr td").filter(function(){
  return $(this).index() == i;
}).css("background", "pink");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width=200 border=1>
<tr>
    <th>Ignore</th>
    <th>Highlight</th>
    <th>Ignore</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>yep</td>
    <td>yep</td>
    <td>yep</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td>yep</td>
    <td>yep</td>
    <td>yep</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you specified column name won't change, you can use jQuery.contains:

```
$( "body > table > tbody > tr > td:contains('Highlight')" ).css('background-color', 'pink');
```

Comment: GrafiCode it's not the `tbody` or the `td` that contains `Highlight`

Comment: I like this solution but it needs to get the header index and use it as a `:nth-child` selector for the `td`'s.

Answer (score 0):

Needed this highlighted in multiple tables: final solution

```
$("th:contains('Highlight')").each(function() {
    $(this).closest('table').find('td:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) +')').css('background-color', 'pink');
});
```